# перевести с mysqli в PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

доброго времени суток, постал вопрос перехода на PDO, есть такая функция как **mysqli_fetch_all**, каков будет аналог для PDO?

```
function get_result($result,$db) {


    if($_GET['res'] == 1) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

как данный пример сделать в PDO?

Comment: Вот не поверите, fetchAll. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воу бро, изучи реально мануал по PDO. Если сложно, то использую [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php), там все просто , еще легче чем, mysqli.

```
R::getAssoc('SQL запрос');
```